# How do I change the Date but not the Time of a Timestamp within a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Python 3.6.0

I am importing a file with Unix timestamps.
I’m converting them to Pandas datetime and rounding to 10 minutes (12:00, 12:10, 12:20,…)

The data is collected from within a specified time period, but from different dates.
For our analysis, we want to change all dates to the same dates before doing a resampling.

At present we have a `reduce_to_date` that is the target for all dates.

```
current_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-04-05')  #This will later be dynamic
reduce_to_date = current_date - pd.DateOffset(days=7)
```

I’ve tried to find an easy way to change the date in a series without changing the time.
I was trying to avoid lengthy conversions with `.strftime()`.

One method that I've almost settled is to add the `reduce_to_date` and `df['Timestamp']` difference to `df['Timestamp']`.  However, I was trying to use the `.date()` function and that only works on a single element, not on the series.

GOOD!

```
passed_df['Timestamp'][0] = passed_df['Timestamp'][0] + (reduce_to_date.date() - passed_df['Timestamp'][0].date())
```

NOT GOOD

```
passed_df['Timestamp'][:] = passed_df['Timestamp'][:] + (reduce_to_date.date() - passed_df['Timestamp'][:].date())
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

I can use a loop:

```
x=1
for line in passed_df['Timestamp']:
    passed_df['Timestamp'][x] = line + (reduce_to_date.date() - line.date())
    x+=1
```

But this throws a warning:

> C:\Users\elx65i5\Documents\Lightweight Logging\newmain.py:60: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>   See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

The goal is to have all dates the same, but leave the original time.
If we can simply specify the replacement date, that’s great.
If we can use mathematics and change each date according to a time delta, equally as great.
Can we accomplish this in a vectorized fashion without using .strftime() or a lengthy procedure?

Comment: Look at the [.dt accessors](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) in Pandas for non-index datetime columns added functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert `df['Timestamp'].dt.date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), because output of [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) is `python date object`, not `pandas datetime object`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':pd.to_datetime(['2017-04-05 15:21:03','2017-04-05 19:10:52'])})
print (df)
            Timestamp
0 2017-04-05 15:21:03
1 2017-04-05 19:10:52

current_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-04-05')
reduce_to_date = current_date - pd.DateOffset(days=7)

df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'] - reduce_to_date + pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].dt.date)
print (df)
            Timestamp
0 2017-04-12 15:21:03
1 2017-04-12 19:10:52
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Comment: That did the job exactly as I had hoped.
I struggled with that for a couple hours before coming here.
I knew it might be simple, I just couldn't find the correct syntax or method.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can simply subtract an offset

```
passed_df['Timestamp'] -=  pd.offsets.Day(7)
```

***demo***

```
passed_df=pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(['2017-04-05 15:21:03', '2017-04-05 19:10:52'])
    ))

# Make sure your `Timestamp` column is datetime.
# Mine is because I constructed it that way.
# Use
# passed_df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(passed_df['Timestamp'])

passed_df['Timestamp'] -=  pd.offsets.Day(7)

print(passed_df)

            Timestamp
0 2017-03-29 15:21:03
1 2017-03-29 19:10:52
```

---

***using `strftime`***
Though this is not ideal, I wanted to make a point that you absolutely can use `strftime`.  When your column is datetime, you can use `strftime` via the `dt` date accessor with `dt.strftime`.  You can create a dynamic column where you specify the target date like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(passed_df.Timestamp.dt.strftime('{} %H:%M:%S'.format('2017-03-29')))

0   2017-03-29 15:21:03
1   2017-03-29 19:10:52
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I originally tried using the Offset, but since I have 4+ dates I couldn't use a simple offset of .Day(7)  
That would just move each date by 7 days, but they still wouldn't be the same.  
I tried using an inline equation to dynamicaly assign the Day, but that threw some errors.  

I did see some examples of using strftime, but that seemed to bulky and to not really be the best Python method.